# "File ended while scanning use of \@item." Confusion

Tags: errors

What does this error imply? Is there a thing I am forgetting at the end of my document to complete it? This is the only error I am receiving in TeXstudio.

Comment: I removed the texstudio tag as the errors in a document are unrelated to the editor that you use to write the document.

Answer (score 3):

`\@item` is the internal version of `\item` so the error means that you have

```
\item[something
```

with no matching `]` so TeX read to the end of the file looking for `]`

The full error message gives more context, so for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[aaa
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
Runaway argument?
aaa \end {itemize} \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \@item.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*>
```

Note the error message shows the text that TeX had consumed looking for the argument so in this case everything from `aaa` to `\end{document}`  so this pinpoints the error to just before `aaa` so the `\item[` here.